# Need to replace "\x2D" on a extracted variable at Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I was working with on a Jmeter script.
At the 1st Response I have extract a lengthy code which I have to pass to the next request.
Unfortunately, the 1st request contains "\x2D" characters , which need to be replaced with "-".
Is there any way to do this.
I tried with below code on a `BeanShell PostProcessor`, but its giving me an error.

```
def originalValue = vars.get("BE_stateToken");
def newValue = originalValue.replace("\x2D", "-");
vars.put("myVar", newValue);


log.info("Variable myVar value: " + vars.get("myVar"));
```

Below are the errors I'm getting.

> 2023-08-29 14:17:48,365 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error
> invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:  `def originalValue = vars.get("BE_stateToken"); def newValue = originalValue.re . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: def not found in namespace 2023-08-29 14:17:48,365 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`  def originalValue =
> vars.get("BE_stateToken"); def newValue = originalValue.re . . . '' :
> Typed variable declaration : Class: def not found in namespace 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot help you without seeing the details of the "error" you're getting. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.

The code is almost fine, you just need to escape a backslash with another backslash:

```
def newValue = originalValue.replace("\\x2D", "-");
```

[image]

You can also consider using [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup), in this case you won't need to do any scripting. It can be installed as a part of [**Custom JMeter Functions**](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks, @Dimirti, I was able to replace the string with the help of your response.